# How to prevent minipage from going to the next page?

Tags: page-breaking, minipage, figure-placement

I would like to place a figure in the space at the bottom of the page.  The figure is as large as the space.  But when I try to place the figure there, the figure goes to the next page.

The figure is in a minipage.

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{figure.png}
\end{minipage}
```

If the image is smaller it will fit there, if larger it will go to the next page.

I would like to place the image on the same page without making it smaller.

Comment: If the image makes the `minipage` larger than the available space (even a tiny bit), LaTeX will place the whole `minipage` on the next page. You could try setting the `height` of the image instead of the `width`. You could also try to put some negative space before the `minipage` (but this is probably rather the last restort). Why do you place the image in a `minipage` at all?

Comment: the minipage is doing nothing useful there you can simply use `\includegraphics`

Comment: Of course, it will probably still got to the next page.  OTOH, you could `\enlargethispage`, specify the height of the minipage and/or add negative `\vspace`.